# JPA entity field value different from its DB representation

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to define with JPA / Hibernate a mapping between fields of an entity and their representation on DB columns? I desire a bidirectional mapping on read/write operations:

```
@Column(name = "DEGREES")
int degrees;
```

For example, I want to read this field in Celsius, but I'd like to update the corresponding DB column in Fahrenheit.

or better example

```
@Column (name = "BASE64STR")
private String asciiStr;
```

read ASCII text, but update a base64 value to DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `@Transient` fields, this way you have an attribute that is not persisted and you can add custom read logic to it. For example:

```
@Column(name = "DEGREES")
int degreesCelsius;

@Transient
int degreesFahrenheit;

public getDegreesFahrenheit() {
    return this.degreesCelsius * 9/5 + 32;
}
```